# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on build web site

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-remoting

I have a web site that is just serving as a Remoting Server and has remoting configuration inside its `web.config` file.

```
<system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <service>
        <activated type="abc.def.ghi"/>
      </service>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http" machineName="localhost"/>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
```

## Besides this web.config file, it has only these files in it:

dataConfiguration.config
enterpriseLibrary.config
log.config
website.publishproj
bin folder - which has the DLLs that are served from this project via remoting

When I build the web site, I receive build error which is:

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

How can I debug what's causing this error and how to remove it?

Please advise.

Comment: Ok, what made you think the problem lies in your web.config and not in the website itself you're trying to build?

Comment: I thought it is serving the objects from the assemblies which are present in the bin folder and they are configured to be served in the `web.config` as `<activated type=""/>` elements. Besides these two things - the bin and web.config, I can't guess what can be the cause.

Comment: Build errors usually point to a specific line of code...You really don't have to guess, you just need to read the message (`WHOLE MESSAGE`) and find out which line is the problematic one. We can't debug this for you by looking at your web.config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I had a assembly reference in my `web.config` where there was a version mismatch between it and the assembly present inside the bin folder:

```
<add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when Target framework is not selected. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfSBL.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).