# Strange Visual Studio 2012 compilation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, build

Ever since I upgraded from VS2010 to VS2012 I am experiencing a strange compilation issue. I have searched the web quite a bit and haven't found a bug report, so I'm wondering if anybody here has run into a similar issue. Can it be fixed?

EDIT: I am running VS2012 Update 2 on Windows 7 x64 with all patches applied.

Sometimes, especially when compiling the entire solution just after checking-out from SVN, one of the projects fails to build with an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. After this, if I hit build/rebuild again, it works! It doesn't happen all the time, so I have no idea why. I have checked the solution, the project and its references and there doesn't seem to be anything odd with it.

The build window shows something like:

```
... blah blah, everything fine ...

114>------ Build started: Project: C:\...\mymainwebproject\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
114>Validating Web Site
114>: Build (web): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
114>
114>Validation Complete

... blah blah, everything fine ...


========== Build: 118 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And the error window looks like (my reputation is too low to post images yet here's the link):

`http://i.imgur.com/piSfLR8.png`

Any feedback is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: See if this link helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280965/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-on-build-web-site

Comment: Thanks, that would make sense. You have l33t search skills :) I will update the question if I confirm this later.

Comment: Seems to me the most likely cause is covered in this other question, although i have not confirmed it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209465/tracking-down-intermittent-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?rq=1